# Extending images to edges of screen (bleed) with CSS to Kindle

Tags: kindle, epub, editing, formatting

Kindle Create has a new feature called "image bleed". It extends an image past the left and right margins by placing it on the edge. I'm wondering how to reproduce it, is there a way to create it in CSS? I am creating the e-book in epub format with Sigel editor.

The image bleed is ignored if I export to epub format on Kindle Create. Only in the KPF file does it work well.

Answer (score 0):

Even in a Windows environment using ADE eReader it still sets it all back to "aligned with text" (no full screen width spread). Full screen width spread is usually intended for PRINT books.
It's doubtful that full image spread would ever work on most eReaders (due to the way an epub functions and due to the way most eReaders design their software for the surrounding device edge gap space).

That being said, KDP likely has some kind of internal code overwrite that allows that "full screen or page spread" to function in their KPF format ONLY. Getting other eReaders (or any .epub) to accept that kind of code would be like chasing moonbeams.

I opened an exported KDP Epub  (one that had full screen width image spread in it) to see if that specialized CSS was exported but not utilized. The only code it exported was width:100% and text-align; no specialized image spread capability.

So...what you can experiment with....
Here are several links describing methods for full image spread across the web screens (for CSS web page use). You can experiment with these and perhaps find success somehow.
[CSS Tricks - bleeds](https://css-tricks.com/full-bleed/)
[And another link on bleeds](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2020/css-html/full-bleed-layout-using-simple-css/)

Info about KDP paperback book image bleed.
[KDP image bleed](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GVBQ3CMEQW3W2VL6)

Full width mage bleed link you asked about:
[KDP image full width bleed](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G7R2L7V5X6SJH948#images)